# In VS Code, can I enable or disable extensions on a per-workspace basis?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a lot of projects to maintain; they require different plugins to operate. But, some plugins are heavy and make VS Code slow.

I want a plugin-set to be applied when I open one project and not to others.
In this way my VSCode will be light-weight.

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to Extensions (CTRL+SHIFT+E) in the Activity Bar, click the cogwheel next to an extension and select **Disable (Workspace)**. Apparently it's also possible to disable an extension globally, and make it activate only if it's explicitly enabled in `{workspace}/.vscode/settings.json`.

[image: It's possible to disable extensions per workspace]

Answer (score 1):

As @Artur said, you have to either have to disable or enable each extension by workspace.  Not the most elegant of solutions.

Better solutions have been requested a few times, see [workspace settings for extension lists](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40109) and [persisting extension load with a manifest file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39272).  The feature seems desired but no real indication of movement on the issue other than what Artur said.